# App as foreign key

Tags: python, django

So , i have a django project with 2 **apps**

```
├───Blog
    post
    comment

└───User
    profile
```

- user (basic authentification and profile dashboards)
- blog (having basic blog models : post,comment)

I need to give the users the possbility to create one or more blogs within the same project, but i don't see how i can treat an app like a model.

The only solution i figured out , is to add a foreign key to user id for every model withn the blog app.but is there a better way ?

Comment: can't you just add a Blog model and add a foreign key to user with a related name?

Comment: but Blog is an app that has many models, and not a single model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do that:

```
# blog/models.py

class Blog(Model):
    owner = ForeignKey(User, related_name="blogs")
    name = Charfield()

class Post(Model):
    blog = ForeignKey(Blog, related_name="posts")
    #Other fields ...

class Comment(Model):
    post = ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    #Other fields ...
```

Comment: True , not for saas based apps that need security and db separation